# How do I get a programmatically imported file to show in Files and image display?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom object with a NoteID that I import along with two images related to it. I manually build the objects associated with uploading an image in code using an UploadFileMaintence graph. I can see the objects linked together in the database properly, and when I navigate to the custom detail page, the files show them as uploaded:
[image]

However, when I click on the Files(2) button, when the dialog box comes up, I see nothing within the dialog:
[image]

Here are the four related tables (CustomTable, NoteDoc, UploadFile, and UploadFileRevision):

CustomTable showing noteID and CheckURLName:
[image]

NoteDoc showing NoteID to FileID relationship:
[image]

UploadFile:
[image]

UploadFileRevision:
[image]

Code to generate image upload entries:

```
    protected void AddDetailRow(List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> keypairs, InventoryItem givingType, string temp, UploadFileMaintenance graph)
    {
        //NOTE string temp contains the temporary directory address I created.
        CFBSContributionDetail detail = Details.Insert();
        //Code to populate detail object
        //NOTE: the variables front and back get populated with the file name of the image related to them.
        Details.Update(detail);

        this.Actions.PressSave();

        PX.SM.FileInfo frontInfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo(front, null, File.ReadAllBytes(temp + front));
        frontInfo.RevisionId = 1;
        frontInfo.Comment = front;
        frontInfo.UID = Guid.NewGuid();
        PX.SM.FileInfo backInfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo(back, null, File.ReadAllBytes(temp + back));
        backInfo.RevisionId = 1;
        backInfo.Comment = back;
        backInfo.UID = Guid.NewGuid();
        PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(Details.Cache, detail, frontInfo);
        PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(Details.Cache, detail, backInfo);
        Details.Update(detail);
        this.Actions.PressSave();

        UploadFile frontFile = new UploadFile();
        frontFile.FileID = frontInfo.UID;
        frontFile.Name = front;
        frontFile.Versioned = true;
        graph.Files.Insert(frontFile);

        UploadFileRevision frontImage = new UploadFileRevision();
        frontImage.FileID = frontInfo.UID;
        frontImage.Data = frontInfo.BinData;
        frontImage.FileRevisionID = 1;
        frontImage.BlobData = frontInfo.BinData;
        frontImage.Size = frontInfo.BinData.Length;
        graph.Revisions.Insert(frontImage);

        graph.Actions.PressSave();

        UploadFile backFile = new UploadFile();
        backFile.FileID = backInfo.UID;
        backFile.Name = back;
        backFile.Versioned = true;
        graph.Files.Insert(backFile);

        UploadFileRevision backImage = new UploadFileRevision();
        backImage.FileID = backInfo.UID;
        backImage.Data = frontInfo.BinData;
        backImage.FileRevisionID = 1;
        backImage.BlobData = backInfo.BinData;
        backImage.Size = backImage.BlobData.Length;
        graph.Revisions.Insert(backImage);

        graph.Actions.PressSave();

        detail.CheckImageUrl = front;

        Details.Update(detail);

        this.Actions.PressSave();
    }
```

One thing I noticed is that the image URLs stored in the UploadFile -> Name column are the screen type followed by a random set of numbers. I'm not sure how to generate that or if I even need to generate that. The files I'm uploading are of .TIF format, but I'm going to be changing them to .PNG since .TIF do not display within the browser.

If there is a better way to perform this task, I'm open to completely changing what I've done so far.

EDIT: I added code to transform the .tif files into .png files before uploading them.

Comment: Have you tried PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(DACCache, DACRecord, file.UID.Value); instead of PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile?

Comment: Also it could be related to file types, try using a more standard filetype like '.zip'. I think we have limited upload by file types or at least different logic.

Comment: I thought it might be the file type, but I added code to convert the images to .PNG before uploading. I still have the same results. I did upload, manually, a .tif file to a detail and it does show when I click the Files action within the Files Action popup. I will try the SetFileNotes, but I thought that was just for notes and not actual files.

Comment: I successfully transformed into PXNoteAttribute.SetFilesNotes(), but it still isn't showing the .png files in the File Action popup. I've also added it to the detail page on RowSelected to make sure the files have been added, but still nothing is showing. Am I missing creating any database entries that might finish this link? I feel like I'm one step away from completing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the lines `graph.SaveFile(frontInfo);` and `graph.SaveFile(backInfo);` after I finished creating the FileInfo objects. Adding those lines fixed it