# Save Image file on persist method

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to save image file that's been copied from screenshot and pasted into the PXImage control. Now, when I save the record I am trying to save the image as well and save the name of the file in database record along with other DAC fields.

Below is the js code that sets the screenshot image into the PXImage control.

```
document.onpaste = function (event) {
    var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // will give you the mime types
    if (items.length > 0) {
        var imgControl = document.querySelectorAll('.note-m img');
        //get the last screenshot
        var item = items[items.length - 1];
        if (item.kind === 'file') {
            var blob = item.getAsFile();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var result = event.target.result;
                imgControl[0].src = result;
                px_alls["ds"].executeCallback("saveScreenshotImage","test");
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when I press (Ctrl+V) on the screenshot.
[image]

Now, I want to save this image and generate a file name that I can save on DAC field called 'ScreenShotImage' along with the record.

I thought of creating an action and calling that via js but I couldn't succeed on passing image as a command argument.

Action method in graph:

```
public PXAction<Ticket> saveScreenshotImage;
        [PXButton]
        public virtual IEnumerable SaveScreenshotImage(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            throw new PXException("test...");
        }
```

Calling via JS

```
px_alls["ds"].executeCallback("saveScreenshotImage");
```

Is there any way, I can get that particular file on Persist method?

```
public override void Persist()
        {

            base.Persist();
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if you need something this complex, but here is how I uploaded images directly to custom objects through an imported zip file. The logic to save the image may be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324417/how-do-i-get-a-programmatically-imported-file-to-show-in-files-and-image-display. I hope this helps some.

Comment: After reading it seems like user has to upload the files by themselves(correct me if I misunderstood.) but what I want here is, I want user to just press print screen key,  go to submit ticket form, select the details and press paste (that would paste the image from last clipboard image.
Now, I have manged to read the base64 string of the image file(which i am planning to convert it into the byte[] and save it up as a file.), so I need some way to send either image or that string( i have created a custom non persistent field) via javascript to store that string value in DAC.

Comment: The hard part is even I set the value of textarea (which contains the base64 string value of image), it is not being updated while I trigger the Persist method.

Comment: Is your question how do you get the file from the JSON function to the BLC?

Comment: Yes. I want to send this js result 'var result = event.target.result;' to Persist method of BLC.